# PHPExcel file is unsafe when open

Tags: php, phpmailer, phpexcel

When I use the script to attach a excel file at send it as email, opening the file from the mail client it says that the file is corrupted or not formated correct. How can I remove that message. The data in the cells is OK.

```
$objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007($objPHPExcel);
$objWriter->save("php://output");
$data = ob_get_contents();

$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->addAddress('mail@mail.com');

$mail->AddStringAttachment($data, '123.xls')  

$mail->Subject = 'Excel';
$mail->Body    = 'Excel file';

if(!$mail->Send()) {
echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
echo "Message sent!";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're giving an OfficeOpenXML (`.xlsx`) file an extension of `.xls`, so MS Excel will complain....

```
`Excel5` Writer     ->  BIFF-format           ->  `.xls` file extension
`Excel2007` Writer  ->  OfficeOpenXML-format  ->  `.xlsx` file extension
```

Comment: When I cange it to xlsx it cannot open the file

Comment: `Cannot open the file`?!? What version of MS Excel? What error does it give? Does it have problems if you use the `Excel5` Writer with the `.xls` extension?

Comment: Excel 2016 (same problem with Excel 2010) It just says: the file cannot be opened because the fileformat or filetypename is unvalid.

Comment: `fileformat or filetypename is unvalid.` that will happen if you're using `Excel5` Writer for `.xlsx` or `Excel2007` Writer for `.xls`.... could it simply be that MS Excel is aware that the file is downloaded from the interwebz/emailed and therefore simply isn't trusetd? https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Trusted-documents-cf872bd8-47ec-4c02-baa5-1fdba1a11b53

Comment: hmm maybe. I use 
include 'PHPExcel/Writer/Excel2007.php';

Comment: The file is empty when I opening it with notepad

Comment: Well they're wrong on that github snippet.... does sending a static Excel file (generated using normal Excel) via email give the same messge?